# What do these question marks above enemy heads mean?

Tags: terraria

I just noticed something weird. Whenever I hit an enemy with [the beekeeper](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Bee_Keeper), a little question mark pops up over their head. For example:

[image]

So what exactly is this? Does it only apply to the beekeeper? I assume it has something to do with the recent 1.3.3 update, since I don't remember this in any previous versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [Confused](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Confused) status effect. The Beekeeper only has a 10% chance of inflicting that status effect, and it's the only weapon pre-hardmode that can inflict this kind of damage.

Comment: You can get access to Confusion pre-Hardmode in Expert Mode with the [Brain of Confusion](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Brain_of_Confusion).

Comment: @Michaellogg that's not a weapon, though, that's an accessory.

Comment: Some I'm guessing the question mark is just a new visual indicator of the "Confused" status? Cause that never came up before.

Comment: @GeoHam The beekeeper wasn't introduced until 1.2, and before that confuse effects were quite rare, only appearing in certain biomes.

Comment: I have played 1.3 before, but never seen the question mark until 1.3.3

Comment: @GeoHam And you used the Beekeeper before 1.3.3? or any of the other 4 confusion items? Or fought hardmode monsters?

Comment: Yes, I used the beekeeper before, and I also completed the whole game. TBF, I didn't use the beekeeper very much, so maybe I just never noticed it.